# Update list view at particular interval

Tags: android, listview

Having a list view with some details, I have data inflated in list view from server. So on create of activity I have called a api to get data and inflated to list view once. And also pagination is there in list view,so on scroll to last item it will again call api for next page and append data of next page at end of list. This works fine. 
But what I want is kind of auto referesh of list view data at some interval. Means list view to have kind of updated data.How I need to architecture my activity to obtain solution I want.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Thread downloadThread;

boolean isRunning = true;
```

In onCreate() :

```
downloadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (isRunning) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000); // run at every 10 seconds
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // Write your code here to update the UI.
                                updateListData();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }); 

       downloadThread.start();
```

Thanks.

Comment: This would update list on some interval,and on scroll to last item I am updating list data.. how to handle both does not occur on same time..

Comment: @chitra you can deal with this `isRunning` flag. when you updating list data on scroll then you can set `isRunning = false` that will stop this thread to execute. And once you done with that you can again set `isRunning = true` to start thread execution again.

Comment: this thread will execute at interval and get a batch of data say 1-10 items.. on scroll i will call next page so it will give me next data set.. so i have some 20 items.. here  i am done with scroll. and so my thread will again execute and give me updated data from 1 -10 items again.. so my list should show 10 items now or 20 items because once page has been scrolled..? I am little confuse on how to handle data set on auto refresh n pagination..

Comment: yeah I got on how to stop thread execution at time of scrolling..   can you please suggest me how do I handle my data set.. i am bit confused over here..

Comment: @chitra I think you need to maintain your `data count` within your `onScroll` action. Like say if first 10 record is queried then `count` value will set to 2, so next time it will fire query for `count*10`, so it will fire upto 20th record. something like that.

Comment: @chitra if this solution helps you to solve your problem then you can accept this solution. Thanks.

Comment: I am having issue in this.. every time a activity is created a new thread is created. so multiple thread will be created every time i navigate to that activity each calling api to update data.. How to solve this thing.

Comment: @chitra check the condition like this `if(downloadThread.isAlive() == false)`  before starting this thread.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity's `onCreate()` create a [Hanlder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and then choose what suits you from `post()`, `postAtTime()` or `postDelayed()` and call your refresh method.

Comment: will it not conflict data,as on scroll to last item in list view I am making a server call and on particular interval I also need to make a call. How to handle both call.

Answer (score 0):

use following to update listview

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            callFunction();
        }
    }, 3000);
```